# How to start a PHP Websocket server on Microsoft Azure?

Tags: php, azure, websocket, azure-web-app-service

I was able to setup WebSocket on Azure.[WebSockets enabled on Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC5nu.png)

But my issue is : how to start the PHP ws server?

I have used this sample implementation https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets successfuy on my computer but I am not able to start the server in MS Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Azure Web Apps run in a secure environment called a sandbox. In the sandbox, each app is processed by Microsoft IIS. An app runs through PHP's Command Line Interface (CLI) is not allowed. For more details, please refer to [Azure Web App sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox).

In order to be able to run [`PHP-WebSockets`](https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets) in Azure, you need to host in something like a Virtual Machines, Cloud Services, or Containers, rather than Web Apps.

Comment: Ok thank you.  I will have to find an otherway to use websockets oin Azure Web App